# issue KendoUI and SpringMVC with json binding

Tags: json, spring-mvc, kendo-ui

When I use a grid KendoUI, there is a problem with SpringMVC and jackson.

In fact, the grid datasource take a json with the format :

```
[{"name":"Apple","description":"a description","value":15}]
```

However, SpringMVC serialize it like :

```
{"name":"Apple","description":"a description","value":15}
```

without square bracket in String, so this grid doesn't bind values.

e.g code :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Product get(Model model) {
    Product app = new Product("Apple", "a description", 15);
    return app;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/product/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getJson(Model model) {
    return"[{\"name\":\"Apple\",\"description\":\"a description\",\"value\":15}]";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dataSource.schema.parse](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) to manually intercept and parse that string representing your JSON into valid JavaScript Array.

Comment: Thank you Petur for you response!

I understand the KendoUI mechanism. The server method needs to return only an Array (or a Collection), in order to have brackets..

Answer (score 0):

Below should work. Kendo Grid is expecting a JSON array, thus the block quotes.

For READ :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Product> list() {
      Product apple = new Product("Apple", "a description", 15);
      List<Product> listProduct = new ArrayList<Product>();
      listProduct.add(apple);
      return listProduct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Product[] get(Model model) {
    Product app = new Product("Apple", "a description", 15);
    return new Product[]{app};
}
```

or

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Product> get(Model model) {
    List<Product> product = new ArrayList<Product>();
    product.add(new Product("Apple", "a description", 15));
    product.add(new Product("Guice","a guice",3));
    return product;
}
```